# Fastlane - use current git tag as version number

Tags: zsh, fastlane

I'm trying to use the latest tag on a branch as the version number in an iOS project, using Fastlane.

If I run `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags` in my terminal I can see the latest tag output.

I'd like to pipe this value into `increment_version_number` in Fastlane.

To test this I have run -

```
fastlane action increment_version_number(version_number: $(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags))
```

in my terminal, but the output I get is

```
zsh: unknown file attribute: v
```

[increment_version_number docs](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/increment_version_number/)

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the command in the terminal has a different syntax - you need to supply the arguments inline.

```
fastlane run increment_version_number version_number:$(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags)"
```